# Filter on hight of number in textfile

Tags: php

ive been trying this by splitting the lines with substring and than  using array unique on it but I cant get it to work properly. the idea is... if the same line is in the file with a lower number... keep the line with the higher number.
 textfile:

```
wood    tiger    22324    Squirrel
john    apple    24574    Squirrel                                  
peter   snuggle  21234    Squirrel                                  
james   coolest  20108    Squirrel                                  
james   coolest  20134    Squirrel
```

output needed:

```
wood    tiger    22324    Squirrel  
john    apple    24574    Squirrel                                  
peter   snuggle  21234    Squirrel                                  
james   coolest  20134    Squirrel
```

so it basically has to keep the highest numbered item if its the same line (the higher the number the newer the line is).

What I've tried so far:

```
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "rb" , FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);


while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    if ($line_of_text[0] === ' ') continue;  
        if ($line_of_text[0] === ' ') continue;  

    $part1 = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...); 
    $part2 = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...);
    $part3 = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...);
    $part1 = explode(' ', $part1);
    $part1 = array_unique($part1);
    $part1 = implode(' ', $part1);      
var_dump ($part1);
}       

file_put_contents('outputfile.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));

?>
```

Comment: 1) Any reason you wouldn't want [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) used in an answer? 2) Any reason not use `explode` on `$line_of_text`?

Comment: well... I had a reason for it but it did not work out that well haha...... so no real reasons for 1 and 2

Comment: i see your problem.... i cant figure it out...

Comment: is your file really separated using spaces? or are those tabs that got converted?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your "final" values in an associative array as you loop through the file. Compare each row to the array before adding it to avoid duplicates.

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("test.csv", "rb" , FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$finalArray = array();
$numberPartCol = 1;

while (($line_of_text = fgets($file_handle))) {
    if ($line_of_text[0] === ' ') continue;
    // why check the same thing twice?

    // going to assume you have this part working as you didn't ask about it
    $uniqueKeyPart = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...);
    // remove all the spaces so we can compare the numbers
    $numberPart = str_replace(" ", "", substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...));
    $squirrelPart = substr("$line_of_text", ..., ...);

    if(!array_key_exists($uniqueKeyPart, $finalArray)) {
        $finalArray[$uniqueKeyPart] = array(
            // use preg_replace to get rid of all the extra whitespace
            // if you don't want the spaces at all, just use str_replace as above
            preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $uniqueKeyPart),
            $numberPart,
            preg_replace("/ +/", " ", $squirrelPart)
        );
    }
    else {
        if($finalArray[$uniqueKeyPart][$numberPartCol] < $numberPart) {
            $finalArray[$uniqueKeyPart][$numberPartCol] = $numberPart;
        }
    }
}

// loop through $finalArray to put the data in the format you want for the outputfile.txt
$lines = array();
foreach($finalArray as $row) {
    $lines = implode(",", $row) . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('outputfile.txt', $lines);

?>
```

[fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Please do consider changing how the data is stored in the first place. My sympathies if you have no control over that :(